# TeamCity composite build trigger

Tags: teamcity

Is there any way to configure composite build trigger on TC?
For example

```
Finish Build Trigger of project_1 (successful build only)  
and
Finish Build Trigger of project_2 (successful build only)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for a particular build you can have only one among '`VCS trigger` - to run on specific folder set/** change ; `Schedule` + `Retry` build trigger'.

But you can achieve composite trigger by adding '`Finish Build Trigger`' & by selecting checkbox option '`Trigger after successful build only`' in first build as shown below:

[image]

some details here: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+Finish+Build+Trigger

**OR**

But back to your question: I think you should be able to handle with 2 or more '`Build Steps`' if you are good to run '`project_2`' build on SU run of '`project_1`'

In '`Build Triggers`' have trigger rules defined only for '`Build Trigger of project_1`'.

And in Build Steps handle with - checkout part of '`project_2`' & run needed build instructions.